# speed and position of vehicular status are not consistent reasonably in Veins,omnet++ and sumo

Tags: omnet++

Used: Omnet++4.6, Sumo0.21.0 and Veins-3.0
I tried to track a vehicle using RSU when a vehicle continuously send a beacon(WSM) contained Vx(velocity to x-axis),Vy(velocity to y-axis),position,speed in **every second**.I used open-street-map for this scenario. After recorded beacon message(WSM) trough RSU,I found followings:

t0=0.839078378444 id=0 x0=299.711 Vx0=-0.0273485 y0=542.695 Vy0=-1.58621 AngleRed0=1.58804 Speed=1.58645
t1=1.839078378444 id=0 x1=299.665 Vx1=-0.0607238 y2=540.03 Vy2=-3.52198 AngleRed1=1.58804 Speed=3.5225

I used following code to set the properties in WSM in vehicle node which has been retrieved from RSU's onBeacon method:
    wsm->setSpeed(traci->getSpeed());
    wsm->setAngleRad(traci->getAngleRad());
    wsm->setvecX(traci->getCurrentSpeed().x);
    wsm->setvecY(traci->getCurrentSpeed().y);
    wsm->setSenderPos(traci->getCurrentPosition());
    wsm->setCarId(getParentModule()->getIndex());

Now Calculation to check Vx and Vy are consistent:
At time t1 = 1.839078378444,(x1,y1) = (299.711,542.695),(x2,y2)=(299.665,540.03)
d=√(-0.046)²+(-2.665)² =  2.665396 So,1.588 = 91.032ᶿ, Cos(91.032)= -0.018008156, Speed=2.665396/1,Vx=Speed*Cosᶿ,Vx = 2.665396*Cos91.032=2.665396*(-0.018008156)= -0.0479 **is not consistent** with Vx0(-0.0273485)
Vy= 2.66496 **is not consistent** with Vy0(-1.58621) and same for the others records. Therefor, d/t=speed=2.665396 **is not consistent** with speed=3.5225. Any advise or solution or clarify the concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your car seems to be speeding up.

If I understood you right, at the two time instants you measured, SUMO reports the car's speed first as 1.6 m/s, one second later as 3.5 m/s.

In my view, the distance you calculated (2.67 m) is reasonable. You would expect your car to travel somewhere in-between 1.6 m and 3.5 m, which it does.

Note that, when you calculated the speed, you flipped the sign in y direction: remember that OMNeT++ uses a coordinate system where (0,0) is the top left.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This means that the speed reported by the SUMO is the instantaneous speed not the average speed during the previous time step, right?  
A related question: does SUMO add noise that are expected in car sensors to the reported measurements of position and speed?

Comment: The default car following model of SUMO uses discretized movement where each car stores its instantaneous position and speed from one time step to the next. See, for example, Eq (6.1) in [Stefan Krauß Dissertation](http://sumo.dlr.de/pdf/KraussDiss.pdf). Reporting average speed would offer no immediate benefit, as it can be easily derived from position samples.